# Discord server channel lister not working

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-3.9

I'm trying to make something that can list all the channels in a server of your choice, but it won't work.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
token = ('TOKEN')

@client.event
async def on_connect():
    print("What server do you want to list?")
    find_guild = input("")
    for guild in client.guilds:
        try:
            if guild.id == find_guild:
                print(guild)
                for channel in guild.channels:
                    try:
                        print(f'    {channel}')
                    except:
                        print("Failed")
        except:
            print("Failed")

client.run(token)
```

(I removed my token for reasons)

I think that the issue is that the "if guild.id == find_guild:"
won't work.

Comment: "It won't work" is not an adequate problem statement. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service, you should narrow down a specific problem you are facing. For more information, please see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `find_guild = input("")` is returning a `str`, the [`guild.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.id) is an `int`, so comparing the two will always return `False`

Convert the input to an `int` using `find_guild = int(input(""))` and your code should work as intended.